# Regex: How to match digits not followed by any characters but allow characters after space?

Tags: javascript, regex

Need help making a regex match with these criteria(pardon me for my possibly confusing phrasing).

1. Only match if starts with a number or dot
2. Match number, dot, and whitespace in between
3. Match until first space if nondigits follow that space
   If only numbers follow the space then match it
   If any characters except a dot, whitespace, or number follow a number then return null.

So far I've gotten this, but it still allows special characters to follow the numbers after.

```
/^[0-9\.][0-9\.\s]+(?!\w)/
```

Sample results

```
"1500" should return "1500"
"1500 0" should return "1500 0"
"1500 a" should return "1500"
"1500&" SHOULD return null, but so far returns "1500"
"1500a" should return null, as it should.
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to escape `.` within a character-class

Comment: What should return `1500      a` (with several spaces)?

Comment: @Jarod42 Just the number I guess, but my input wont give me more than one space so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[\d.][\d\s.]*(?!\S)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZVFZ4c/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B%5Cd.%5D%5B%5Cd%5Cs.%5D*(%3F!%5CS)):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[\d.]` - a digit or a dot
- `[\d\s.]*` - 0 or more digits, whitespaces, dots, as many as possible
- `(?!\S)` - followed with a whitespace or end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['1500 0', '1500 a', '1500&', '1500a'];
var rx = /^[\d.][\d\s.]*(?!\S)/;
for (var i=0; i < strs.length; i++) {
  var m = strs[i].match(rx);
  if (m) {
    console.log(strs[i], "=>", m[0]);
  } else {
    console.log(strs[i], "=> NO MATCH");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/YRXtjG/5)

```
^[\d\.][0-9\.]+((\s(?=\w)\d*)|$)
```

**Explanation:**

1. `^` start of the string
2. `[\d\.]` match a char of number of digits or dot
3. `[0-9\.]+` match any number of digits or dots
4. `(\s(?=\w)\d*)` match white space, look-ahead of alphanumeric chars and 0 or more occurrence of digits
5. `|$` or end of the string if not match condition no 4.

**JS Example:**

```js
let match = null, pattern = /^[\d\.][0-9\.]+((\s(?=\w)\d*)|$)/;

match = '1500 0'.match(pattern) || [null]
console.log(match[0])

match = '1500'.match(pattern) || [null]
console.log(match[0])

match = '1500&'.match(pattern) || [null]
console.log(match[0])

match = '1500 a'.match(pattern) || [null]
console.log(match[0])

match = '1500a'.match(pattern) || [null]
console.log(match[0])
```